# python: 'socket' object attribute 'bind' is read-only

Tags: python, sockets

I saw a similar question been asked a year ago but no solution was found for the problem. Hope to find it now.
I'm trying to figure out how does network programming work and found this code example of a basic server:

```
import socket                                         
import time

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999                                           

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)      


while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    currentTime = time.ctime(time.time()) + "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(currentTime.encode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

But as I run the code it says that 'socket' object attribute 'bind' is read-only. I tried to replace both ip  to '0.0.0.0' and port number to 8080 or just ' ' but nothing worked.

Comment: Could you post the complete traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 14, in <module>
    serversocket.bind = ((host, port))
AttributeError: 'socket' object attribute 'bind' is read-only

Comment: @AlexL, LOL, dude, the code you posted in your question is different. You should be _calling_ `bind`, not assigning stuff to it.

Comment: @ForceBru, suppose. Could you give an example what the code must be like as I'm a total noob or where to check some examples?

Comment: The code which you posted here is a working sample only.

Comment: @AlexL, the code in your question is the example. The place to check for examples is the Python Documentation, certainly.

Comment: @ForceBru, only now got what you meant in first comment (still struggle with tech English) got it, thank you a lot